# Symfony2 custom validator

Tags: validation, symfony

i am trying to build an custom validator with symfony2 but something strange happens:

i have created both Password and PasswordValidate by following the steps in [symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) but first time when i load the page i get this error:

```
AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Password" in property NMSP\MyBundle\Entity\User::$password does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

after reloading  the error disappears and the validation still not fires and it return the code is valid.

here is the relevant code:

```
//annotation declaration:
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="32", unique="true")
 * 
 * @Assert\MinLength(3)
 * @Assert\Password2()
 */
protected $password;

//load files with the following in the code
services:
  validator.password:
    class: NMSP\MyBundle\Validator\PasswordValidator
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: password }
```

can`t figure this one out:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your custom validator constraint is not in the Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints namespace, but your own namespace: NMSP\MyBundle\Validator.

You should add the following use statement:

```
use NMSP\MyBundle\Validator as NMSPAssert;
```

Then use the following annotation on the `$username` property:

```
@NMSPAssert\Password()
```

That should do it.

Comment: still need a little more help. i can not figure out how to access the database within de custom validator and how to get the value of an other entity property like for verifing(password = passconf)...i reread the documentation but they don`t talk about this:(

Comment: You probably have figure it out, but here is the answer to your question from the comment above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934607/symfony2-doctrine-validation-constraint-which-requires-access-to-a-database