# Symfony2/Doctrine - validation constraint which requires access to a database

Tags: doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity `ArticlePattern`, which has a property `pattern` (string). I need to access the database to check if pattern is correct. So I would like to define a method `ArticlePattern::isPatternValid()` and add a constraint (using Doctrine's annotation) which would check if isPatternValid is true during validation by Validator object.

From what I have read here and there it is not a good idea, to make an entity depended on service container, which mean I cannot access the doctrine service from inside ArticlePattern::isPatternValid().

So how can I make a custom validation constraint which need an access to the database? How do you deal with such situations which I think is very common seeing so many questions about accessing a service container from an entity class.

**EDIT:**

Ok, thanks guys, so the answer is a [Custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: could you please post complete example of your validation code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A validator object can be:

- A simple object, that has no connection to the framework environment at all.
- A service (in the context of [dependency injection container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Automatically_injected_dependency)) which could do absolutley anything as long as it impements `Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidatorInterface`

So what do you have to do?

1. Define a simple constraint
2. Override `validatedBy()` method to return validator "name" (`return 'my_validator';`)
3. Define a simple service in DIC:

   ```
   <service id="project.validator.my" class="Project\Constraints\MyValidator">
       <!-- service definition here -->

       <!-- the service has to be tagged -->
       <tag name="validator.constraint_validator" alias="my_validator" />
   </service>
   ```

---

#### EDIT

You've asked about multiple properties validation. In such a case you could create a validator that is related to the object rather to the property of the object.

1. In your constraint class define the target of that constraint (property / class):

   ```
   class MyConstraint ... {
       ...

       public function targets() {
           return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Annotate validated class instead of property:

   ```
   @Assert/MyConstraint(...)
   class MyClass {
       private $firstName;
       private $lastName;

       @Assert/Email
       private $email;

       ...
   }
   ```
3. The validator itself looks pretty much the same as in case of validating a property:

   ```
   class MyValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
       public function isValid($value, Constraint $constraint) {
           // $value is an object rather a property
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I have another problem now. In my validator I need an access to the doctrine service as well to other fields of the object under validation (not only that one field). How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Ok, there is a method ConstraintValidator::$context->getRoot() which may hold the reference to the object under validation. I will check it.

Comment: As a follow up, I posted another question, maybe you will be able to help there as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961083/why-errors-from-custom-validation-constrain-not-attached-to-specific-field-by-to

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint should override the base `validatedBy()` method and return the id of the constraint validator service in your container.

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'my_pattern_validator';
}
```