# Why errors from custom validation constrain not attached to specific field by to the form?

Tags: symfony

I have an ArticelPattern class which has $extraPatterns property. This property is an array of ExtraPattern (class) elements.

There is a custom constraint on the class ExtraPattern (which I apply using annotation).

For form handling I created an ArticelPatternType class with extraPatterns collection field.

Now, when I validate this form and there is a constraint violation raised by one of the elements of the ArticelPattern::$extraPatterns collection, the error isn't assigned to that element, but instead to the whole form, so I can't display this error beside the appropriate form field which caused this error.

Instead of putting my custom constraint on the ExtraPattern class, like this:

```
/**
 * @AssertApl
 */
class ExtraPattern
```

I also tried putting it on the collection property, like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\All(@AssertApl)
 */
private $extraPatterns;
```

But with the same result. @AssertApl constraint errors caused by elements of this collection are not assigned to them, but to the whole form.

Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You class constraint is probably being mapped to a form of `form` type, which has `error_bubbling` enabled by default. Setting this option to `false` should do what you're looking for.

```
$builder ->add('extraPatterns', 'collection', array(
    // ...
    'options' => array('error_bubbling' => false),
));
```

Comment: 'error_bubbling' => false works like charm :) But It is a little bit strange, that when I put the @AssertApl constraint directly on the collection element class (not the collection itself by @Assert\All) the errors are still bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

Belongs to similar problem: use `firstName` in your entities **and forms**. Not `first_name`.

If your entity (User) has field like `firstName`, form builder accepts `form_field` (with underscore) field naming. It saves data correctly and so on. But if you would add some custom constraint to this field, be careful with underscore: don't use it. Use `camelCaseFieldNames` insted or you'll get errors attached to form, not to field.

Comment: great! here you are an official discussion about it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9162