# One to many validation unique field with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Request entity with many Interventions like this :

Request.php

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Intervention::class, mappedBy="request")
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, max=3)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $interventions;
```

Interventions.php

```php
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("today +3 days")
     */
    private $idate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", options={"unsigned": true})
     * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=23)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $ifrom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", options={"unsigned": true})
     * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=23)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $ito;
```

I want to validate that in the case of multiple interventions that the idate is unique. How to do ?

I have see that for **@Assert\Unique** constraint : `6.1 The fields option was introduced in Symfony 6.1.`. But i am using Symfony 5.4...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with :
[How to validate unique entities in an entity collection in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782056/how-to-validate-unique-entities-in-an-entity-collection-in-symfony2)

And this one link :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25401